# WordPress user generated content plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'v been crawling the net for a plugin that will allow visitors to create a post with or without registration, I found a few solution but none of them had the WordPress text editor (word style).

Do you happen to know a plugin that allow visitors to create posts and categorize them easily using the WordPress plugin, and all of that without registration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) and [FV Community News](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fv-community-news/) would be two great options. Both will will allow you get user generated content without registration, but Gravity Forms may give you more options on customization and categories.